# create observables dynamically and show it in html ,knockout?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, knockout.js

HTML :-

```
<div  class="row" style="margin-left: 10px;" data-bind="foreach: {data: data, as: 'data1'}">
<span style="color: red; display: none;" data-bind="attr:{'id':data1.mandatory!=0?'id'+data1.dynamicid:''},text: 'You have selected ' +app.vm.observables.totalSelected()+ ' Observation areas. Please restrict to only 2.'"></span>
</div>
```

here the observable is same for every div element id so value is showing same how to do it dynamically?

JAVASCRIPT :-

```
`$('#id'+dynamicid+' input:checkbox.paramValues:checked').each(function(e){
DataImprove++;
});`
if(DataImprove>2){
vm.observables.totalSelected(DataImprove);
}
```

Need to create observables dynamically based on the div element ids and show it in the frontend HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to do, but hopefully this helps
I think it would make sense to move some of the functionality out out the view and into a viewModel

```js
var externalData = [{
  mandatory: false,
  dynamicid: 1,
}, {
  mandatory: false,
  dynamicid: 2,
}, {
  mandatory: 1,
  dynamicid: 3,
}, {
  mandatory: false,
  dynamicid: 4,
}];




function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.data = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.totalSelected = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.data().filter(function(i) {
      return i.selected() === true;
    }).length;
  });
  self.selectedText = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    return 'You have selected ' + self.totalSelected() + ' Observation areas.';
  });

  var mappedData = externalData.map(function(item) {
    return {
      mandatory: item.mandatory,
      dynamicid: item.dynamicid,
      selected: ko.observable(false),
      mandatoryStatus: item.mandatory == true ? 'mandatory' : ''
    };
  });

  self.data(mappedData);

}
var vm = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
.mandatory {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<span data-bind="text: selectedText"></span>

<ul data-bind="foreach: {data: data, as: 'data1'}">
  <li data-bind="class: mandatoryStatus">
    <label data-bind="text: dynamicid"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selected" />
  </li>
</ul>
```